# aligning dynamic buttons in gridlayout

Tags: java, android

> I am trying to align dynamic buttons in `Grid layout`.

**Problem:**

> However, if text is more than one line the formation of buttons in row
>   is not as needed.
>
> String item[] =  new String[]{"item1", "item2", "item3 yes",
>   "item4","item5"};
>
> Button[] myButton = new Button[item.length];

```
GridLayout scrViewButLay = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    scrViewButLay.setColumnCount(4);
    scrViewButLay.setRowCount(10);
```

// GridLayout.LayoutParams leftMarginParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
       //     );

```
 for (int index = 0; index < item.length ; index++) {


        myButton[index] = new Button(this); //initialize the button here
        myButton[index].setText(item[index]);
        myButton[index].setHeight(100);
        myButton[index].setWidth(100);
        myButton[index].setTag(index);

        scrViewButLay.addView(myButton[index]);

    }
}
```

[image: output image]
`

Comment: why don't you use an Adapter?

Comment: i m new to android can u tell me any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use an Adapter and then customize however you want
check out this example
http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76

Comment: Thank you for the example but when i copy and paste codes in android studio. The 'GridAdapter' is not recognised. Isnt there any way to control the childs of gridlayout instead of using gridview?

Comment: download source code and import it don't just copy and paste!

Comment: Thk u its working, but it creates another problem i need to use getTag or getID functions on click of each item. but not working from main activity class

Answer (score 0):

I think using a recyclerView with GridLayoutManager should help you out.

This post https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/ should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to apply a layout_gravity as the default seems to be to align the text to be the same height (this is why it only happens with the item 3 with two lines).

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    param.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    param.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```