# Using custom adapter in dynamic buttons

Tags: java, android

I am trying to extend base adapter and return an button view. The app is crashing at the start. First section of code shown below are creating arrays of type button. The second set of code are using customising the base adapter.

```
GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);



    for (int index = 0; index < Item.length; index++) {
        //  TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);

        myButton[index] = new Button(this); //initialize the button here
        myButton[index].setText(Item[index]);
        myButton[index].setWidth(120);
        myButton[index].setHeight(120);
        myButton[index].setId(index);
        //myButton[index].setTag(index);
      //  scrViewButLay.addView(myButton[index]);
       // gv.addView(myButton[index]);
        myButton[index].setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(myButton[index]));

    }
    gv.setAdapter(  new CustomGridAdapter( this, myButton ) );


public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private final Button[] gridValues;

//Constructor to initialize values
public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, Button[ ] gridValues) {

    this.context        = context;
    this.gridValues     = gridValues;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    // Number of times getView method call depends upon gridValues.length
    return gridValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}


// Number of times getView method call depends upon gridValues.length

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // LayoutInflator to call external grid_item.xml file

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from grid_item.xml ( Defined Below )

        gridView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.starters , null);



        Button b0 = (Button) gridView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

       // String arrLabel = gridValues[ position ];



    } else {

        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}
```

ERROR

```
06-30 04:44:23.672 7633-7633/com.CITAQ.peripheraltest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.CITAQ.peripheraltest, PID: 7633
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.CITAQ.peripheraltest/com.CITAQ.peripheraltest.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                            at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:482)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2153)
                                                                            at com.CITAQ.peripheraltest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5976)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: please post the log.

Comment: i have added error in question above

Comment: to be displayed see question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752326/aligning-dynamic-buttons-in-gridlayout/44752585#44752585